# How to change for loop to store items in a list for writing

Tags: python, csv

I have this code, and based on the outcome of my script in a .csv (only one UserID was printed repeatedly) I'm assuming that my variable is overwritten and reassigned each iteration.

```
# User_alias is a raw input (of multiple items)

    print user_alias
        for user in user_alias:
            for row in Dict_list:    
                if user in row.values():
                    print row

        for user in user_alias:
            for row in Dict_list:
                if row.has_key('_akq6p') and row.has_key('_cn6ca'):
                    if user == row['_akq6p'] or user == row['_chk2m']:


#EDIT:
                    UserID = row['_cn6ca']
                    UserIDs=[]
                    UserIDs.append(row['_cn6ca'])
                    print UserIDs
```

Here is a sample Input/output:

```
Raw input:
Adue Sal
Arthur Bel
Abby Sue

['Adue Sal', 'Art Baraan', 'Abbey Shi']
{'_akq6p': 'adkul', '_dcgjs': 'adkul', '_chk2m': 'Adue Sal', '_cn6ca': '1200df00'}
{'_akq6p': 'artb', '_dcgjs': 'artb', '_chk2m': 'Arthur Bel', '_cn6ca': '00123ffj8'}
{'_akq6p': 'abbys', '_dcgjs': 'abbys', '_chk2m': 'Abby Sue', '_cn6ca': '125gh789'}
['1200df00']
['00123ffj8']
['125gh789']
logout

[Process completed]
```

I need to write these into a .csv, so I need to store each ID but this code seems to only store the last ID that was looked up.  How would I store all of these ID's for later writing?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input so we can run the code as well?  It helps to provide sample input and output so we know what you're looking for.

Comment: Create an empty list `userIDs = []` then in the innermost loop do `userIDs.append(row['_cn6ca'])`. Agree with other comment, adding sample input (and expected/desired output, preferably a http://sscce.org/, etc) will give your question a much better chance of being answered usefully.

Comment: I added in a sample input/output. It looks like a list of 1 item is being created and rewritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ran: http://codecube.io/TlFgaY

You need to create the list outside of the loop, and then add to it.

```
print user_alias
for user in user_alias:
    for row in Dict_list:    
        if user in row.values():
            print row

UserIDs = [] # This is the change.
for user in user_alias:
    for row in Dict_list:
        if row.has_key('_akq6p') and row.has_key('_cn6ca'):
            if user == row['_akq6p'] or user == row['_chk2m']:
                UserID = row['_cn6ca']
                print UserID
                UserIDs.append(UserID)

print UserIDs
```